# MS Access: Using year in a column name?

Tags: ms-access

When I try to name a column like so:

`(year(now())+1) & " Revenue" : Revenue0`

It literally displays (year(now())+1) & " Revenue" and not "2013 Revenue"

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Normally you would have a year column in the table and use that in your grouping/aggregation for the revenue for that year, then you could pivot the table if needed (cross tab).  But a link here says someone else did what you want http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=msaccess%20expression%20in%20column%20name&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pcreview.co.uk%2Fforums%2Fuse-expression-field-name-query-t3421747.html&ei=AEKdULCkIOi7igKsnYD4Dg&usg=AFQjCNHoecSmIG7FK5WgDZmoTWFeV9jUBQ.

Answer (score 1):

AFAICT, you want the db engine to derive the alias for a query field expression, similar to this ...

```
SELECT 1234.56 AS Year(Date()) & " Revenue";
```

Unfortunately, that throws an error: "*The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.*"

The db engine can't use functions to derive an alias; you can only give it a literal string value for the alias.

You could run a saved query from a function which alters the query's SQL property.  That would allow you to replace the alias with a different string value.

If your saved query is named "qryFoo" and contains this as its SQL ...

```
SELECT Revenue0 AS REVENUEYEAR
FROM YourTable;
```

... you could do this ...

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("MyQuery")
qdf.SQL = Replace(qdf.SQL, "REVENUEYEAR", Cstr(Year(Date())+1) & " Revenue")
```

Then open the revised query.

Comment: The SQL is wrong. You supposed to use the format of select "some expression" as "some column name". You have "some expression" as "some function". Try somthing like  SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, year(date()) as MyYear
FROM customers;